# 'future' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, compiler-construction, g++

I would like to know why my compiler complains when I test the following code :

```
int main(int argc, char**) {    
...
std::future<int> result( std::async([](int m, int n) { return m + n;} , 2, 4));
...
return 0;
}
```

It gives: error: ‘future’ is not a member of ‘std’

I have  gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.7.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the [`<future>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/future) header and switch on C++11 support with compiler flag `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Much amaze, such knowledge! :) Upboat!

Comment: Thanks! I am using CMAKE and I have added set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11") and add_definitions("-std=c++11") to the CMakeLists.txt file and when I do a make it says: "Could NOT find Boost" and later it says: "CMake Error: Unable to open check cache file for write. /home/cpp-driver-master/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache".

Comment: @user3532527 No idea. That is quite unrelated to the question you posted.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that I was using CMAKE tool! I had to set the flag to c++11 as you recommended and the errors came just right after!

Comment: @user3532527 Still, that is a separate issue.

Comment: Alright, I will post a separate question for it, but thanks for your answer for the compiler flag!